# iText 5 to iText 7 code conversion. List type AcroFields

Tags: itext, itext7

I am have following iText 5 example for pdf modification,

```
public static void modifyPdfForRequestMap
(
    HashMap<String, String> fieldValuesMap, 
    String srcPdfFile, 
    String outFile, 
    boolean formFlatten,
    boolean xfaForm,
    boolean fieldManipulateFlag         
)
{


    PdfReader reader = null;
    PdfStamper stamper= null;
    HashMap<String, String> modifiedFieldNamesMap = null;

    if(fieldValuesMap != null) 
    {
        try
        {
            reader = new PdfReader(srcPdfFile);     

            if(fieldManipulateFlag)
            {                   
                AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields(); 
                String[] fieldNames =  null;
                if(fields != null)
                {
                    Map<String, Item> formFields = fields.getFields();
                    if(formFields != null)
                    {
                        Set<String> fldNames = formFields.keySet();

                        fieldNames = new String[fldNames.size()];
                        int i =0;
                        for (String fldName : fldNames) 
                        {   
                            fieldNames[i]=(fldName);                 
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(fieldManipulateFlag)
                {
                    modifiedFieldNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    if(fieldValuesMap != null && !fieldValuesMap.isEmpty() 
                        && fieldNames != null && fieldNames.length > 0)
                    {
                        Iterator<String> keys = fieldValuesMap.keySet().iterator();

                        while (keys.hasNext()) 
                        {
                            String key          = (String) keys.next();
                            String value        = (String)fieldValuesMap.get(key);
                            int fieldsCount     = fieldNames.length;

                            for(int i=0; i <fieldsCount; i++)
                            {
                                String fieldName = fieldNames[i];

                                if(fieldName != null 
                                    && fieldName.indexOf("."+key+"[") != -1)
                                {
                                    modifiedFieldNamesMap.put(fieldName, value);
                                }
                                else if(fieldName != null && fieldName.equals(key))
                                {
                                    modifiedFieldNamesMap.put(key, value);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    modifiedFieldNamesMap = fieldValuesMap; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                modifiedFieldNamesMap =  fieldValuesMap; 
            }

            DeleteFile(outFile);

            stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outFile));    

            if(stamper != null )
            {

                AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
                XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
                if(xfa != null && xfa.isXfaPresent() && !xfaForm)
                {
                    form.removeXfa();
                }
                if(form != null)
                {
                    HashMap<String, Item> fields = (HashMap<String, Item>) form.getFields();
                    Iterator<String> iter = modifiedFieldNamesMap.keySet().iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) 
                    {
                        String fieldName    = (String) iter.next();
                        String fieldValue   = modifiedFieldNamesMap.get(fieldName); 
                        int fieldType = form.getFieldType(fieldName);
                        if(fields != null && fields.containsKey(fieldName) && fieldValue != null)
                        {
                            if(fieldType == AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST && fieldValue.indexOf(",") != -1)
                            {
                                form.setListOption(fieldName, fieldValue.split(","),fieldValue.split(","));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                form.setField(fieldName, fieldValue);
                            }
                        }                            
                    }

                    stamper.setFormFlattening(formFlatten);
                }
            }               
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (DocumentException e)
        {       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(stamper != null)
                {                   
                    stamper.close();
                }
                if(reader != null)
                {                   
                    reader.close();
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else if(formFlatten)
    {
        try
        {
            try 
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(srcPdfFile);
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try 
            {
                stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            stamper.setFormFlattening(formFlatten);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(stamper != null)
                {                   
                    stamper.close();
                }
                if(reader != null)
                {                   
                    reader.close();
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    modifiedFieldNamesMap = null;
}
```

I am trying to convert to iText 7 but I have hard time converting last part of the function where List type field value and simple Acrofield values are inserted in to document.

:---------------------------------------------------------------

```
PdfFormField field = form.getField( fieldName );
 int fieldType = form.getFieldType (fieldName);
 if( fields != null && fields.containsKey(fieldName) && fieldValue != null )
 {
 if(fieldValue.indexOf(",") != -1 && fieldType == AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST ) 
     {
         form.setListOption(fieldName,       fieldValue.split(","),fieldValue.split(","));
     }
     else
     {
           form.setField(fieldName, fieldValue);
     }
   }                            
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are there any particular problems you see with this?

Comment: There are many changes in iText 7 (example acroFields.getFieldType() and AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST not found in iText7 ). I am trying to convert following function to iText 7 and facing issues, could not find alternative to methods in iText 5 for iText 7 to rebuild this function.

Comment: What do you think about following a [few of the guides](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-differences-itext-5) on their site to understand the differences?

Comment: @HappyRahul please don't ask on stackoverflow for others to do all your coding for you but instead tell us concrete problems. You say you *"could not find alternative to methods in iText 5 for iText 7 to rebuild this function"*. For which methods in particular? You surely don't want to tell us you found nothing for any class and method, do you?

Comment: @mkl I have edited my question. The exact problem is adding list and simple Field type. I have marked part of code for that.(/****/). Code above that section is converted to iText 7. I posted whole iText5 code so it would be easy to understand, but I will keep your suggestion in mind while posting question on Stackoverflow. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Ivan I am using that from past couple of days, could not find answer for adding List Type field type to acrofield.